# jQuery Draggable, Droppable, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

This is almost exactly what I'm looking for, only would like to find a VB.net solution instead of C#:

[jQuery Draggable, Droppable, ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405396/jquery-draggable-droppable-asp-net-mvc/4140838#4140838)

I have draggable jquery accordions on a page. When the user drags to change the panel order, I want the changed order to be saved in the database so when they come back later, the revised order is what they will see. This is being done in VS2010, VB, ASP.NET 4, and MVC using latest jquery library. Can anyone point me to a VB MVC example for a scenario like this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that demonstrates what you need. It's not exactly the same but you can use the logic of this application.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/100/Experimenting-with-jQuery-Draggables-and-ASP.NET
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/101/Persisting-the-position-of-jQuery-Draggables-in-ASP.NET