# Implementing Drag n Drop using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am developing a MVC application wherein I have to implement Drag n Drop functionality. I also want to get the source as well as target items/ records in the table/ div once the item is dropped on a target place. Then both the source and target values will be passed to the action method defined in the controller to update the same in the database.

Can anyone please suggest some links?

Comment: With what part in particular are you having a problem? What have you tried to do? Do you have a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we could see, and help with?

Comment: @David - I do not have any live demo yet. I am having problems while getting the target element. The functionality is implemented as per the following link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405396/jquery-draggable-droppable-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ to pass your data and jQuery UI sortables http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ for the drag and drop.