# Send data from list to another list then edit in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My goal is to transfert data from a list to another. I was able to populates them, and now trying to do the rest. I want to add 2 buttons between the lists so I can send the data from both sides. I need help to code the button, and how to code the controller so I can collect the selected items in the lists (to remove and/or delete).

Here my model :

namespace OnlineTR.WebUI.Areas.Admin.Models
{
    public class TestCategoryModel
    {

```
   public IEnumerable<TestCase> TestCasesAvailable { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<TestCase> TestCasesCurrent { get; set; }

}
```

}

View :

```
@model Models.TestCategoryModel           

@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.TestCasesAvailable, new SelectList(Model.TestCasesAvailable,"TestCaseId", "TestCaseName"))          

@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.TestCasesCurrent, new SelectList(Model.TestCasesCurrent, "TestCaseId", "TestCaseName"))
```

Comment: have to say that you need to give a more concrete example, when you say "send the data from both sides"...how does list 1 and list 2 would look like...when they are initially loaded...and how they should look like once you transfer the data...

Comment: The 2 list contain TestCaseName. For exemple list1{car, pool} and list2{tv, house, food} . I want to exchange items from one list to the other. Like List1{car, house, food} list2{tv, pool} with 2 buttons(one for each direction).

Comment: Jquery draggable is better. If you can show me that with a simple example, I would be very happy. Because of course, my ultimate goal is to use drag and drop with jquery between the 2 list. But I wanted to start with simple button to understand the whole mecanisme.

Comment: alex, sorry deleted that comment as was gonna expand with answer to question. give me 20 mins :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example post...you may try this...it is similar to your problem...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136730/ASP-NET-MVC-2-Basics-Working-with-ListBoxes

Although it is done in MVC 2...that dynamics/approach will still remain the same in MVC 3...

Comment: Thks a lot. Its exactly what I need. The best would have been drag and drop with jquery. But for What I need, buttons works fine. Your example helped me to understand more about MVC3 (im new in this domain).

Comment: @alex I'm glad that I could help you...you may mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Alex,

I'd take a look at the jquery UI for the swapping scenarios if that is your use case. I've used a similar technique for a project that required ingredient categories to be added from one list to another. for this, I used jquery draggables and then saved the resultant 'list b' elements as part of a form post (via ajax). These examples may help for starters:

- [jQuery Draggable, Droppable, ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405396/jquery-draggable-droppable-asp-net-mvc)
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/drag-and-drop-items-from-one-list-to-another-list-using-jque/

will follow up with more asap

Comment: Thks. Also, can you focus not only in the "view" part, but also the controller. I would like to understand the transition from View to Controller. I was able to feed my model and create the 2 lists, but I not sure I understand how to get back to controller with the right values.